# Fill 2 color for background with Canvas J2ME

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Im new in J2ME, and i very interested in canvas because it can do a lot of work but i have trouble is define coordinate X and Y

I try to fill my screen with 2 color Green and Gray but it miss a part above screen:

I need you help

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second occurrence of `i * size` in [fillRect](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) in [rev 3 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7643447/3) feels slippery

```
    int size = 50;
    for(int i = 0; i < itemsPerLines.length; i++){
         int x = 0 + 1, y = i * size,
                width = getWidth() - 2, height = size /* not i*size */;
         if(i % 2 == 0){
             g.setColor(0x00ff00); // green - not 0x0ff000
         }else{
             g.setColor(0x414141);
         }
         g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
         g.setColor(0xff00ff); // red + blue? wonder how it looks
         int x1 = i * size, y1 = y;
         g.drawLine(x, y, x1, y1);


    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

But i confuse why start Y is i * size and end Y is size? 

I cant imagine that

Comment: you're confused because of your choice of variable names: `start Y` and `end Y` say nothing about their purpose. If you use names from method javadoc (I edited my answer to link to javadoc and use names from there), it would be easier to recognize their purpose which is, well, described in that very javadoc. "`y` - the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled, `height` - the height of the rectangle to be filled". Y coordinate "moves" in the loop that's why `i*size` while height remains the same that's why `size`